# fgets and strtok crashes with Segmentation error after several runs

Tags: csv, fgets, strtok

I have a csv file that I read to get the IP address that I need to do a lookup. I decided to use fgets and strtok to get the IP address in each line of the csv file. The IP address is the 4th token in the file (i started my counter to 0 as the first token) It reads the line, tokenize the record but it does not seem to get out of the while loop to do the rest of the lookup process using the IP address token i found. And in addition it seemed that it does an extra read of the file that causes the Segmentation error in runtime

Here is the code.. hope you can assist as I am new in c and I am trying to use c instead of java since the code runs faster in c

```
#include "GeoIP.h"
#include "GeoIPCity.h"


static const char * _mk_NA( const char * p ){
 return p ? p : "N/A";
}

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE           *f;
  FILE           *out_f;
  GeoIP          *gi;
  GeoIPRecord    *gir;
  int             generate = 0;
  char            iphost[50];
  char            *nextWordPtr = NULL;
  int             wordCount =0;
  char            *rechost;
  char            recbuffer[1000];
  char delims[]=",";
  const char     *time_zone = NULL;
  char          **ret;
  if (argc == 2)
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "gen"))
      generate = 1;

  gi = GeoIP_open("../data/GeoIPCity.dat", GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);

  if (gi == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening database\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  f = fopen("city_test.txt", "r");

  if (f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening city_test.txt\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  out_f = fopen("out_city_lookup_test.txt", "w");

  if (out_f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening out_city_lookup_test.txt\n");
    exit(1);
  }

//** Read the file line by line and get the ip address to use to lookup GeoIP **//
//*     while (!feof(f)) {
   while (fgets(recbuffer,1001,f) != NULL {
         nextWordPtr = strtok (recbuffer,delims); 
         while (nextWordPtr != NULL & wordCount < 5) {
           printf("word%d %s\n",wordCount,nextWordPtr);
           if (wordCount == 4 ) {
               printf("nextWordPtr %s\n",nextWordPtr);
               strcpy(iphost, nextWordPtr);
               printf("iphost %s\n",iphost);
           }    
           wordCount++;
           nextWordPtr = strtok(NULL,delims);
         }
    gir = GeoIP_record_by_name(gi, (const char *) iphost);

    if (gir != NULL) {
      ret = GeoIP_range_by_ip(gi, (const char *) iphost);
      time_zone = GeoIP_time_zone_by_country_and_region(gir->country_code, gir->region);
      printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%f\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", iphost,
         _mk_NA(gir->country_code),
         _mk_NA(gir->region),
         _mk_NA(GeoIP_region_name_by_code(gir->country_code, gir->region)),
         _mk_NA(gir->city),
         _mk_NA(gir->postal_code),
         gir->latitude,
         gir->longitude,
         gir->metro_code,
         gir->area_code,
         _mk_NA(time_zone),
         ret[0],
         ret[1]);
      fprintf(out_f,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%f\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", iphost,
         _mk_NA(gir->country_code),
         _mk_NA(gir->region),
         _mk_NA(GeoIP_region_name_by_code(gir->country_code, gir->region)),
         _mk_NA(gir->city),
         _mk_NA(gir->postal_code),
         gir->latitude,
         gir->longitude,
         gir->metro_code,
         gir->area_code,
         _mk_NA(time_zone),
         ret[0],
         ret[1]);
      GeoIP_range_by_ip_delete(ret);
      GeoIPRecord_delete(gir);
    }
  }
  GeoIP_delete(gi);

  fclose(out_f);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: 03/18/2013 00:05:50.999,UIS,1ZY6471E0490018013,Y6471E,61.175.203.206,zh_CN,NF,CN,02,Ningbo,null,29.878204,121.5495,0,0
03/18/2013 00:06:02.780,UIS,1Z33A2Y00498305491,newnet-au,203.14.65.33,en_GB,,AU,07,Melbourne,null,-37.813904,144.96341,0,0
03/18/2013 00:06:09.767,UIS,1Z93F96F0491667757,93F96F,58.211.161.22,zh_CN,,CN,04,Kunshan,null,31.377594,120.954315,0,0

Comment: revbuffer hs size 1000.  Why are you telling `fgets` that it can hold 1001 bytes?  That's generally a mistake.

Comment: @William, fgets require length to store the length of the line but i have a variable length file.. how do i tell fgets to get the len of the line each time

Comment: You don't.  If you want to dynamically allocate space, you will need to use something like `getline`, or use `fread` and allocate as necessary.  But you absolutely must not tell `fgets` that the buffer is bigger than it is.